# Monthly Average Solar Maps (R.Sun) in Grass

Tags: grass-gis

I'm trying to create monthly average maps as described in R.Sun in Grass. I have my DSM. In reading the page on OSGEO it mentions that it is possible without showing how. Ideas? I assume I will need to write a script.

Comment: We need to update the answers. Things are easier now in GRASS7 within it's temporal framework.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you need to loop over days in a month and then average. Here's attempt at a bash script. The ideas is to calculate the individual solar radiation, and then store the filenames. You can process those with [r.series](http://www.phygeo.uni-hannover.de/grass/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.series.html) to calculate the monthly average.

```
#!/bin/bash
mdoys=( 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334 365 ) 
months=( 'January' 'February' 'March' 'April' 'May' 'June' 'July' 'August' 'September' 'October' 'November' 'December' )
this_month=0
files=""
for ((doy=1;doy<365;doy++)) do

  r.sun -s elev=elevation.dem slop=slope asp=aspect \
        beam_read=beam_${doy} diff_rad=diff_${doy} day=${doy}

  if [[ ${doy} -lt ${mdoys[${this_month}]} ]] ;  then
   files=${files},beam_${doy}
  fi
  if [[ ${doy} -eq ${mdoys[${this_month}]} ]] ; then
   files=${files},beam_${doy}
   echo ${files} > rasters_${months[$this_month]}
   this_month=$((this_month+1))
   # Use r.series to process the files in rasters_January, for example
  fi
done
```

Comment: BTW, I haven't tested it on GRASS, proceed with caution! :) The logic seems to hold, though!

Comment: Just saw this. +1 for indexing in bash. Looks like Python, a bit :-).

Answer (score 4):

Here a link to a plain shell script (rather than the 
bash solution of Jose's comment):
  http://www.grassbook.org/examples_menu2nd.php

Get there: rsun_crop.sh