# Going from hillshade to percent shaded using gdaldem?

Tags: gdal, r, c++, hillshade, gdaldem

I assumed hillshades output percent shaded (scaled to 255) at the given azimuth and altitude but this is incorrect. A flat raster at 80 degrees altitude has a maximum value of 251 instead of 255. How can I go from a hillshade to percent shaded and can I simply divide by the cosine of the 10 degrees in this case to get the correct value or is it more complicated?

Here is some `R` code with `gdaldem` that may help you see what I'm seeing:

```r
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=100,nrow=100)
values(r) <- rep(1,ncell(r))
writeRaster(r,"flatelevation.tif")
system("gdaldem hillshade -az 180 -alt 80 flatelevation.tif hillshade_flat.tif")
hs <- raster("hillshade_flat.tif")
summary(values(hs))
summary(values(hs)/cos((90.0-80.0)*pi/180.0))
```

I will try to parse the [source code](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/apps/gdaldem.cpp) but it's been ten years since I've used C++.

Can someone with general knowledge about hillshades point me the right direction?

---

I thought I could get a "percent of the tile that is shaded" from running a hillshade. Upon further reading a hillshade outputs the illuminance of each tile. So, the cosine is only part of the equation, I would need to pull in the slope and aspect as well for additional trigonometric readjustments, and maybe more.

Turns out there are tools that are functionally equivalent for that I need called "shadow masks" that only output 1 or 0, indicating whether the tile is shaded.

[This](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~decarlo/671/readings/horn81.pdf) nail biting article referenced in `gdal`'s source code helped enlighten me, in addition to [this question on cloud shading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713636/associate-shadows-to-their-source-in-image-analysis), this [question on solar maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/monthly-average-solar-maps-r-sun-in-grass), and this [question on r.sun where a contributor indicates that r.sunmask is slow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/monthly-average-solar-maps-r-sun-in-grass). A couple available tools:

[GRASS r.sunmask](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.sunmask.html)

[RSGISLib Elevation Module: shadowmask](http://rsgislib.org/2_1/rsgislib_elevation.html)

[USGS ISIS Shadow](http://isis.astrogeology.usgs.gov/Application/presentation/Tabbed/shadow/shadow.html)

Of course I need the speed of `gdal`'s hillshading so I'll keep this question up until I or others come up with a solution that can process a 1000 square mile area in a second.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "percent shaded".  For the flat raster case the value of 251 looks correct, because sin(80 degrees)*255 = 251 when rounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the answer is effectively no. You can't get a percent shaded from a hillshade. You can get an estimated shadowed mask. The confusing bit here is that unlike the description [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=How%20Hillshade%20works) `gdaldem hillshade` outputs 1 instead of 0 for shaded tiles. `Postgis`'s `ST_Hillshade` outputs 0 but takes around 20 seconds on my system version 0.5 seconds.